# Filter Active Directory users by Company name, Asp.net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, active-directory

**The Question**

I am looking for a way to filter users from active directory based upon the current logged in users Active Directory Company name (found with the AD profile).

To search AD i am currently using the following code, which returns all users including system accounts -

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain");
var domainUsers = new List<string>();
var userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(context);

using (var search = new PrincipalSearcher(userPrincipal))
{
    foreach (var user in search.FindAll())
    {
        if (user.DisplayName != null)
        {
            domainUsers.Add(user.DisplayName);
        }
    }
}
```

I am looking for a way to only return users that match the Company name of the current AD logged in user. ie if the company name was Test123 the search results would only include all other users that belong to the Test123 company.

**Background**

I am developing an asp.net MVC 2.1 web app that requires a dropdown list of users from active directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Search All users in Active Directory and match against `company` field.

While iterating through a list of all users found based on the query, you can convert the `Principal` to `DirectoryEntry` since Principal doesnt have the information you need. `DirectoryEntry` has the properties that you can look up and work with, in terms of filtering. Only "company" is used in this example.

```
    PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain");
    var domainUsers = new List<string>();
    var userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(context);
    string myCompany = "Test123";
    using (var search = new PrincipalSearcher(userPrincipal))
    {
        foreach (Principal user in search.FindAll())
        {
            string usersCompany = ((DirectoryEntry)user.GetUnderlyingObject())?.Properties["company"]?.Value?.ToString();
            if (user.DisplayName != null && usersCompany != null && usersCompany.Equals(myCompany))
            {
                domainUsers.Add(user.DisplayName);
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

For performance reason, I would recommend using `DirectorySearcher` instead of using `PrincipalSearcher`. Here is the other version. Search is done before the `FindAll()` is executed.

```
    string myCompany = "Test123";
    string searchQuery = $"(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(company={myCompany}))";

    // You can define the fields you want retrieved from AD (Noted by @GabrielLuci)
    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(searchQuery, 
                               new string[] { "DisplayName" }); 
    foreach(SearchResult user in ds.FindAll())
    {
        domainUsers.Add(user.Properties["DisplayName"][0].ToString());
    }
```

Comment: @bsod_ see my update to the post. This is much efficient than the previous PrincipalSearcher.

Comment: +1 for your update. Using `DirectorySearcher`/`DirectoryEntry` is always faster. I actually wrote an article about this: [Active Directory: Better Performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html). A couple ways you could still improve your bit of code is 1. Use `PropertiesToLoad` to only return the attributes you need, and 2. Don't use `GetDirectoryEntry()` - use `user.Properties["displayName"][0]` instead. I explain why in my article.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Always open to suggestions. I do like the use of Properties better and have updated the code to reflect that.

Comment: @GabrielLuci thanks for this! I've replaced company with department and that works brilliantly! How can we add more than one department? "department 1 & department 2"?

Comment: @MannySanchez Use the OR operator, which is `|` - like this: `"(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(|(department=Department1)(department=Department2)))"` You can read more about constructing LDAP queries here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx