# How can I improve the performance for a method

Tags: c#, performance, active-directory

Ive wrote a function to get all Groups with the Members from AD:

```
public static void getGroupsWithUsers() {
        String currentDomain = Domain.GetCurrentDomain().ToString();

        using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, currentDomain))
        {
            using (PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
            {

                foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
                {
                    DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                    var SID = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.ToString();


                    // find a user
                    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, de.Properties["samAccountName"].Value.ToString());

                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        // get the user's groups
                        var groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

                        foreach (GroupPrincipal group in groups)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("User: " + user + " is in Group: " + group);
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

The execution time is around 1,5 seconds for a small amount of data. 
Are there any improvements I could make to get the method faster?
I ask because if I execute the function for 1 million users or groups that it will take forever.

Comment: I would recommend posting that in code review.

Comment: Step 1: profile it. See what's taking the time.

Comment: I will move to the review section. Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend using DirectorySearcher instead of PrincipalSearcher. Read the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59934146/1390548) with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bulk of your problem is what you're doing in the loop. You're taking the search result, converting it to a `DirectoryEntry`, then going back out to the network to find that account that you already just found.

The [`PrincipalSearcher.FindAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalsearcher.findall) method returns a collection of `Principal` objects that you can cast to the type you know they are. In this case, you know it will only return users, so you can cast the result to `UserPrincipal` in your loop.

You're also assigning a `SID` variable that you're not using (although this is likely not taking any significant time).

A side note: You don't need that `currentDomain` variable here, since if you create a `PrincipalContext` with `ContextType.Domain` and no domain name, it will automatically use the current domain.

So your code can be simplified to this:

```cs
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
using (PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
{

    foreach (UserPrincipal user in searcher.FindAll())
    {
        // get the user's groups
        var groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

        foreach (GroupPrincipal group in groups)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User: " + user + " is in Group: " + group);
        }
    }
}
```

That will likely cut the time quite a bit. But if you really want to find the best performance possible, you need to use `DirectorySearcher` and `DirectoryEntry` directly. The `PrincipalSearcher`/`UserPrincipal` classes use those in the background anyway, but you lose a lot of control over what is happening in the background, and that's the key to performance. For maximum performance, you need to cut down on:

1. the number of network requests, and
2. how much data is being sent back.

I wrote a couple of articles on this subject that can help you with that, if you'd like to go down that route:

- [Active Directory: Better performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html)
- [Finding all of a user’s groups](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/08/finding-all-of-a-users-groups.html)

Comment: Hi Gabriel, with you code I get only the groups for Guest?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I had `break;` in there, which I put there just so I could test it for myself. That will make it stop after the first user found. I've removed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to split operations: first - get info to string builder, second - print it.

Like this

```
public static void getGroupsWithUsers() 
{
    String currentDomain = Domain.GetCurrentDomain().ToString();
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, currentDomain))
    {
        using (PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
        {
            foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
            {
                DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                var SID = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.ToString();

                // find a user
                UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, de.Properties["samAccountName"].Value.ToString());

                if (user != null)
                {
                    // get the user's groups
                    var groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

                    foreach (GroupPrincipal group in groups)
                    {
                        stringBuilder.AppendLine($"User: {user} is in Group: {group}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    string result = stringBuilder.Length > 0
        ? stringBuilder.ToString()
        : "No users were found";

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```